# Como contar linhas de código em uma solution .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Quais são todas as soluções (livres ou não) para contar linhas de código em uma solução .NET?

Uso dois Visual Studios: 2012 e 2013.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clique com o botão direito sobre a solução depois clique em **Calculate Code Metrics**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai aparecer esta janela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma outra forma, é usar a tela de pesquisar todos os documentos <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

com a seguinte regex: `^(?([^\r\n])\s)*[^\s+?/]+[^\n]*$`

não esqueça de marcar a caixa de regex

Answer (score 1):

Basta ir no menu Analyze -> Calculate Code Metrics

Uma alternativa seria usar o PowerShell, em que se pode contar todas as linhas que não estão em branco de uma *solution*. Para isso, basta especificar o diretório e a extensão dos arquivos nos quais a contagem será realizada (.cs, .xaml, etc):

```
PS> Set-Location CaminhoDaSolution
PS CaminhoDaSolution> (dir -include *.extensao1, *.extensao2, *.extensao3 -recurse | select-string .).Count
```